# Container not staying up on docker-compose up

Tags: python, docker, rabbitmq, docker-compose

Writing a simple producer/consumer example of RabbitMQ and I am not able to get my consumer container to keep running on `docker-compose up -d`. It should be running on an infinite loop.

[image]

As you can see I can get it to stay up when running `docker-compose run consumer` as well as `docker-compose run -d consumer`

### app.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import argparse
import pika
import json

connection = None
channel = None
TYPES = ['producer', 'consumer']


def producer():
    global connection, channel
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('rabbit'))
    channel = connection.channel()

    channel.queue_declare(queue='hello')

    # Currently a python dict
    data = {
        'key': 'myvalue'
    }

    channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
                          routing_key='hello',
                          body=json.dumps(data))  # Encode as a JSON string
    print(f' [x] Sent {data}')
    connection.close()


def consumer():
    global connection, channel
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('rabbit'))
    channel = connection.channel()
    channel.queue_declare(queue='hello')

    def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
        data = json.loads(body)  # decode JSON string into a python dict
        print(f' [x] Received: {data} type {type(data)}')

    channel.basic_consume(callback,
                          queue='hello',
                          no_ack=True)
    print(' [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C')

    # Infinite loop
    try:
        channel.start_consuming()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('\nExiting...')


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('type', help='producer/consumer')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    client_type = args.type.lower()
    if client_type not in TYPES:
        print(f'{client_type} is not a valid type {TYPES}')
    elif client_type == TYPES[0]:
        producer()
    elif client_type == TYPES[1]:
        consumer()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

As you can see it is fairly straight forward. Copied it basically from the RabbitMQ docs. I ran `docker-compose logs consumer` after writing most of this and got the following.

[image]

Which shows it failing to connect on initial build. It also fails to stay up when running `docker-compose up` even after initial build.

### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  producer:
    build: .

  consumer:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - rabbit
    command: example consumer

  rabbit:
    image: rabbitmq:3.6
```

I used `depends_on` as I thought that should ensure consumer service is built after the RabbitMQ service.

Repo of code is [here](https://github.com/Amertz08/RabbitMQ-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried setting a restart policy for the `consumer` container with the `restart` keyword? What often happens in these situations is that your application tries to connect to a backend service (RabbitMQ in this case) before that service is running and everything blows up. If you set the restart policy, docker will automatically restart the container, and hopefully by this time, your backend service will be up and running.

There are classier ways to do this, but in it's simplest form this would work for you.

You can test my theory out by restarting your consumer container and seeing if it stays up.

```
docker-compose restart consumer
```

Comment: Yeah I was kinda realizing this was likely what was happening after posting it and reading this https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/ I think maybe using the `wait-for-it` script might be a better solution than setting the restart policy to always (which fixed the issue).

Comment: Do you have an opinion on the `wait-for-it` vs simply setting `restart: always` ? I think the restart policy should be `always` regardless.

Comment: I guess it depends on your use case. For simple local development, I am okay with a restart policy. If you plan on using compose in production (not particularly common), you would want to be more careful and use `wait-for-it`.

Comment: Ok. Thanks man it's been a minute since I've used Docker so kinda feel foolish on this one but I also hadn't read or heard about `wait-for-it` so not all that bad.